# NSTableView selection in OS X app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstableview

So I'm trying to learn how to wirte a simple OS X app and I'm a bit confused.

I got this table view - it's already weird to connect it to array controllers etc.

It works fine - for now, but I want to trigger specific action when user taps on a specific row.

I found on stackoverflow about shouldSelectRow method but it seems not to be working correctly.

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
        switch tableView.identifier! {
        case "SetsTable":
            print("Selected row:", row)
            print("Objects after selection:", self.arrayController.selectedObjects)
            self.appsTableView.reloadData()
            return true
        default:
            return true
        }
    }
```

It display correct row in the first print statement, but when it comes to the second one it seems to pick object from completely different row (and if I have one row only with object in it it displays an empty array)

Does anyone know what's the problem here and how to properly display objects for selected row?

Isn't it a problem with shouldSelectRow?

When I use self.arrayController.selectedObjects outside this function (e.g. the row is selected and I tapped a button calling to print out selectedObjects) it displays it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods with 'should' in their name are called before it happens, methods with 'did' are called afterwards.

`tableView:shouldSelectRow:` is called before the selection changes so the delegate can deny the new selection.

`tableViewSelectionDidChange:` is called after the selection changes. `arrayController.selectedObjects` will be the new selection.

If you want to learn more: [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH1-SW1)